# MongoDB - find any document with array combinations

Tags: arrays, mongodb

mongo documents are like:

```
{
    _id: '',
    names: ['ab', 'bc']
}
{
    _id: '',
    names: ['ab', 'de', 'fg']
}
{
    _id: '',
    names: ['bc']
}
{
    _id: '',
    names: ['ab', 'bc', 'cd']
}
```

I have an input array:

```
['ab', 'bc', 'cd']
```

**Question** : How to get all the documents, where 'names' is equal to any combination of the input array ?

**Result** : all documents where 'names' is any of below should return

```
['ab']
['bc']
['cd']
['ab', 'bc']
['bc', 'ab']
['bc', 'cd']
['cd', 'bc']
... and so on..
['ab', 'bc', 'cd']
```

Comment: `db.collection.find({ names: { $in: ['ab', 'bc', 'cd'] }})`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$expr` in `find` to get the `$size` of `$setIntersection` with names array

```
db.tt.find({$expr : {$gt : [{$size : {$setIntersection : ["$names", ["ab","bc","cd"]]}}, 0]}})
```

sample collection

```
> db.tt.find()
{ "_id" : "1", "names" : [ "ab", "bc" ] }
{ "_id" : "2", "names" : [ "ab", "de", "fg" ] }
{ "_id" : "3", "names" : [ "bc" ] }
{ "_id" : "4", "names" : [ "ab", "bc", "cd" ] }
```

with `$expr` and `$setIntersection`

```
> db.tt.find({$expr : {$gt : [{$size : {$setIntersection : ["$names", ["ab","bc","cd"]]}}, 0]}})
{ "_id" : "1", "names" : [ "ab", "bc" ] }
{ "_id" : "2", "names" : [ "ab", "de", "fg" ] }
{ "_id" : "3", "names" : [ "bc" ] }
{ "_id" : "4", "names" : [ "ab", "bc", "cd" ] }
```

with `$in` (as given in comments by Anthony)

```
> db.tt.find({names : {$in : ["ab","bc","cd"]}})
{ "_id" : "1", "names" : [ "ab", "bc" ] }
{ "_id" : "2", "names" : [ "ab", "de", "fg" ] }
{ "_id" : "3", "names" : [ "bc" ] }
{ "_id" : "4", "names" : [ "ab", "bc", "cd" ] }
```